# Why I get an error "client disconnected" when trying to get documents from mongo collection in go?

Tags: mongodb, go

I have mongo capped collection and a simple API, written on Go. I built and run it. When I try to sent Get request or simply go localhost:8000/logger in browser - my process closes. Debug shows this happens, while executing "find" in collection. It produces error "client is disconnected". Collection has 1 document, and debug shows it is connected with my helper.

Go version 1.13

My code:

```golang
func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()

    r.HandleFunc("/logger", getDocs).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/logger", createDoc).Methods("POST")

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8000", r))
}

func getDocs(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    var docs []models.Logger
    //Connection mongoDB with helper class
    collection := helper.ConnectDB()

    cur, err := collection.Find(context.TODO(), bson.M{})

    if err != nil {
        helper.GetError(err, w)
        return
    }
    defer cur.Close(context.TODO())

    for cur.Next(context.TODO()) {
        var doc models.Logger
        err := cur.Decode(&doc) 
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        docs = append(docs, doc)
    }

    if err := cur.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(docs)
}

func ConnectDB() *mongo.Collection {
    client, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Connected to MongoDB!")
    logCollection := client.Database("local").Collection("loggerCollection")
    return logCollection
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you share the code for `helper.ConnectDB()` function?

Comment: Hi, there it is:

func ConnectDB() *mongo.Collection {
 client, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"))
 if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
 }
 fmt.Println("Connected to MongoDB!")
 logCollection := client.Database("local").Collection("loggerCollection")
 return logCollection
}

Comment: @Igor Could you format it and add it to the Q&A please?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#NewClient), the call to `mongo.NewClient` doesn't ensure that you can connect the Mongo server. You should first call [`mongo.Client.Ping()`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Client.Ping) to verify if you can connect to the database or not.

```golang
client, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

if err := client.Ping(context.TODO(), readpref.Primary()); err != nil {
    // Can't connect to Mongo server
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

There could be several reasons behind failing to connect, the most obvious one is incorrect setup of ports. Is your mongodb server up and listening on port 27017? Is there any change you're running mongodb with Docker and it's not forwarding to the correct port?

Comment: Great thanks, it really can’t connect to server, ping failed. Server is on 27017 port, so i will dig this further

Comment: Find it. I must use "client.Connect(context.TODO())" between "NewClient" and any other use of client

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue , read @Jay answer it definitely helped , as I checked my MongoDB was running using "MongoDB Compass" , then I changed the location of my insert statement , previously I was calling before the call of "context.WithTimeout". Below is working code.

```
    package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "time"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

type Book struct {
    Name        string `json:"name,omitempty"`
    PublisherID string `json:"publisherid,omitempty"`
    Cost        string `json:"cost,omitempty"`
    StartTime   string `json:"starttime,omitempty"`
    EndTime     string `json:"endtime,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    client, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    err = client.Connect(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer client.Disconnect(ctx)

    testCollection := client.Database("BooksCollection").Collection("BooksRead")

    inserRes, err := testCollection.InsertOne(context.TODO(), Book{Name: "Harry Potter", PublisherID: "IBN123", Cost: "1232", StartTime: "2013-10-01T01:11:18.965Z", EndTime: "2013-10-01T01:11:18.965Z"})
    log.Println("InsertResponse : ", inserRes)
    log.Println("Error : ", err)

}
```

I can see document inserted in console as well as in "MongoDB Comapass."

Answer (score 0):

In heiper function "ConnectDB" after "NewClient" I must use "client.Connect(context.TODO())"
before any other use of client